# Check if AnyObject is of generic type in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, generics

Let's say that I have generic class *Bus*:

```
class Bus<T> {
    func doSomething() {}
}
```

and I can create instance of it:

```
var myBus = Bus<String>()
```

Now I have a function that takes one parameter of the `AnyObject` and tests it's type:

```
func checkType(object: AnyObject) {
    if let foo = object as? String {
        println("string")
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't see a way to check if `object` is of type `Bus` and run function `doSomething()` if it is of type `Bus`. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit**: Protocols also don't seem to solve this the way they should.

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol BusProtocol {
    func doSomething() -> Void
}

class Bus<T> : BusProtocol {
    func doSomething() -> Void {
        println("asdf")
    }
}

func checkType(object: AnyObject) {
    if let foo = object as? Bus<AnyObject> {
        foo.doSomething() // no match
    }
    if let foo = object as? Bus<Any> {
        foo.doSomething() // no match
    }
    if let foo = object as? Bus<String> {
        foo.doSomething() // prints "asdf"
    }
    if let foo = object as? BusProtocol {
        foo.doSomething() // SIGABRT -- -[SwiftObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
    }
}

checkType(Bus<String>())
```

Comment: Your edit example using `@objc` doesn't appear to segfault with Swift 1.2 – but it does give you an error (which was presumably the problem before, handled less gracefully) that methods in generic classes can't be `@objc` (because Objective-C doesn't support generics).  However, if you drop the `@objc` qualifier on the protocol, it works as hoped (again, using Swift 1.2, which introduced more features around protocols and `as`)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is your thinking of `Bus` as a concrete thing.  It really isn't.  `Bus<String>` is.  `Bus<Int>` is too.  But `Bus` isn't, at least not in the same sense.  You need to know what `T` is.

Really, what you want is to write something like this:

```
func checkType<T>(object: AnyObject) {
    if let foo = object as? Bus<T> {
        println("Bus<T>")
    }
}
```

But if you try and use it, you'll get an error:

```
// error: Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.
checkType(myBus)
```

Unlike in other languages, you can't write `checkType<String>(myBus)`.  But the following might do what you're looking for:

```
func checkType<T>(object: AnyObject, T.Type) {
    if let foo = object as? Bus<T> {
        println("Bus<T>")
    }
}

checkType(myBus,String.self)
```

This fixes what `T` is for any `Bus<T>` and will work correctly.

You might object that you don't want to specify what `T` is.  However, instead, this leads to the question... once you've figured out that `object` is some kind of `Bus`, what are you going to do then?  Are you planning on calling methods on it, or passing it as an argument to other functions?  Chances are what you're trying to achieve can be better done with a generic function and protocol constraints, rather than using `AnyObject` and casting.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 2.x you can use a protocol to achieve this, as you attempted without error:

```
protocol Busish {
  func doSomething() -> Void
}

class Bus<T> : Busish {
  func doSomething() {
    print(self)
  }
}

func with_any_bus(obj:AnyObject) {
  if let b = obj as? Busish {
    b.doSomething()
  }
}

with_any_bus(Bus<Int>());
with_any_bus(Bus<String>());
```

output:

```
swiftblah.Bus<Swift.Int>
swiftblah.Bus<Swift.String>
```

This may or may not be helpful to you specifically, since you seem to be using 1.2, but maybe someone else who stumbles on this question will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I was able to write an empty protocol to use to check if a class was my generic class. No functionality, I just wanted a check.

Answer (score 0):

You've practically got it.

```
func checkType(object: AnyObject) {
    if let foo = object as? Bus<AnyObject> {
        print("Got here")
    } else {
        print("Fail")
    }
}

let bus = Bus<String>()
checkType(bus) // Fail

let otherBus = Bus<AnyObject>()
checkType(otherBus) // "Got Here"
```

I know that's not really what you want, but it shows what Swift needs.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried it. It throws `Argument for generic type 'T' could not be inferred`

Comment: Oh I understand what you're asking now. You need to know what <T> is on Bus itself? Do you care what type Bus contains?

Comment: I just need to check if object is some kind of `Bus` and be able to run `doSomething()` if it is.

Comment: `AnyObject` will not recognize here.

Comment: Seems like perhaps you want something like a Java wildcard, but I don't believe Swift has anything like that.